# File-like operations without the file?

Tags: python

I'm working on an automation tool that will copy a series of commands to a file on a remote system and then ssh to the remote system and execute that file. I'm looking at the docs for paramiko, which has the needed sftp and ssh command capabilities I'll need.

However, I'm noticing that the paramiko.SFTPClient.put() method takes the name of a local and remote path as arguments. I'd like to be able to not have to write the file locally first, and find a way to have SFTPClient.put take in a file-like object instead of pointing to an actual file.

Is there a way to do this within python by handing SFTPClient.put() an object reference instead of a file path, or via a named pipe if SFTPClient.put() can't handle anything that's not an actual file?

Comment: Or maybe a better idea would be to use paramiko.SSHClient.exec_command('echo $list_of_commands > /tmp/remote file && sh /tmp/remotefile') ? Will this break if $list_of_commands contains EOL chars?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply [open](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/paramiko.SFTPClient-class.html#open) the file and write to it:

```
from __future__ import with_statement    
import contextlib

with contextlib.closing(sftpClient.open('file.name', 'w')) as f:
   f.write('myData')
```

Comment: You should really use a `with` expression there.

Comment: @Voo Added `with`. It's technically nicer, but `contextlib.closing` makes it kinda ugly for file- *like* objects.

Comment: Sure it's not perfect, but still nicer than the try{} finally{} approach you'd need otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is [StringIO](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html).

Comment: Nope, it's not. `StringIO` creates a file-like object, and you can't put that into `put` either.

Comment: uh i see. phihag's solutions seems straight forward, though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with paramiko, but you could use the tempfile-module to create temporary files.

```
from tempfile import mkstemp
from os import remove, fdopen
from os.path import exists

file, path = mkstemp()
file = fdopen(file)
# do stuff with paramiko

file.close()
if exists(path):
    remove(path)  # delete the file
```

**Edit**: Corrected code so it uses the not-deprecated and safer function of the tempfile-module.

Comment: `mktemp` is insecure and therefore deprecated. The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.mktemp) mostly consists of reasons *not* to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I really never saw that. I corrected the code-snippet.

Comment: Missed that last line. Better now ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of implementing it by yourself, you can use Fabric: http://docs.fabfile.org/
Fabric has bunch of useful API calls to execute commands on remote machine.

If you are indeed inclined to do it by hand, then use [NamedTemporaryFile](http://docs.python.org/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile).
SFTP is file protocol, so it makes sense to prepare file beforehand and send it.

If you really don't want to prepare file, use this: [SFTPClient#open](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/paramiko.SFTPClient-class.html#open)